# Podman macvlan network error

Tags: networking, debian, podman

## Prerequisites

I am trying to migrate from docker to podman for production use of some containers. Some of my containers are in need to be assigned IP adresses from a DHCP server in my network, as such I used [docker-net-dhcp](https://github.com/devplayer0/docker-net-dhcp).

Now, as I understand, while it cannot be used in docker to do this, the `macvlan` driver in podman can.

### Steps to reproduce

Here are the steps I have done so far:

1. Ensure my (physical) network interface exists:

   ```bash
   ip addr show enp7s0
   2: enp7s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group 
    default qlen 1000
   link/ether 50:e5:49:36:fd:ee brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
   inet 10.0.1.115/24 brd 10.0.1.255 scope global dynamic enp7s0
      valid_lft 59635sec preferred_lft 59635sec
   inet 10.0.1.22/24 brd 10.0.1.255 scope global secondary dynamic enp7s0:1002
      valid_lft 59635sec preferred_lft 59635sec
   [ipv6 ommitted]
   ```
2. Create the podman network:

   ```bash
   sudo podman network create -d macvlan -o parent=enp7s0 newnet
   ```

   and verify

   ```bash
   sudo podman network inspect newnet
   [
       {
           "name": "newnet",
           "id": "884e74728f045cb5209bbaf5e5cf35f1ab7640b11e74ec988fc08ddf97575cf7",
           "driver": "macvlan",
           "network_interface": "enp7s0",
           "created": "2022-06-19T16:45:29.660485744+02:00",
           "ipv6_enabled": false,
           "internal": false,
           "dns_enabled": false,
           "ipam_options": {
               "driver": "dhcp"
           }
       }
   ]
   ```
3. Try setting up a test container from a minimal image, and attach it to the network `newnet` and ask for its ip address:

   ```bash
   sudo podman run -it --rm --net newnet alpine ip addr
   WARN[0000] Failed to load cached network config: network newnet not found in CNI cache, falling back to loading network newnet from disk
   WARN[0000] 1 error occurred:
    * plugin type="macvlan" failed (delete): cni plugin macvlan failed: error dialing DHCP daemon: dial unix /run/cni/dhcp.sock: connect: no such file or directory

   Error: plugin type="macvlan" failed (add): cni plugin macvlan failed: error dialing DHCP daemon: dial unix /run/cni/dhcp.sock: connect: no such file or directory
   ```

## Problem Statement

While I obviously can see what went wrong here, I don't have any idea how to fix it. Can you point me in the right direction?

### Additional Information

#### Debian version

```bash
sudo lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
Release: 11
Codename:       bullseye
```

#### Installed Packages (shortened to relevant ones)

```bash
sudo apt list --installed
Listing... Done
containerd.io/bullseye,now 1.6.6-1 amd64 [installed]
containernetworking-plugins/unknown,now 100:1.1.1-1 amd64 [installed]
containernetworking/unknown,now 100:1.1.1-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
containers-common/unknown,now 100:0.48.0-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
podman/unknown,now 100:4.1.1-1 amd64 [installed]
python3-podman-compose/unknown,now 100:1.0.3-1 all [installed]
python3/stable,now 3.9.2-3 amd64 [installed]
```

#### Podman

```bash
sudo podman --version
podman version 4.1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems I had a misunderstanding in what the CNI plugin for podman is capable of doing.

Upon reading [this blog post](https://xaviercovis.github.io/IP-from-DHCP-podman/), it became apparent to me that the podman CNI plugin must be run as a separate service in order to distribute DHCP leases from the DHCP in host's network to the macvlan.

These are the steps which need to be taken:

1. Create a macvlan

   ```bash
   sudo podman network create -d macvlan -o parent=enp7s0 newnet
   ```
2. **Test** the CNI plugin

   ```bash
   sudo /usr/libexec/cni/dhcp daemon &
   ```

   and once the daemoin is running, start an example container

   ```bash
   sudo podman run -it --rm --network newnet alpine ip addr
   ```

   *One very import observation I made, is that the (virtual) interface inside the container is always called `eth0@eth0`, even despite my (physical) parent interface is called `enp7s0`, which I found confusing at first*
   *One other observation I made, is that the parent interface was locked as in-use by a previously running docker container. In my case, stopping and disabling all docker container services and rebooting helped. I wonÄt need those anymore, as I am moving them to podman anyway.*
3. Once the test completed successfully, make the daemon a permanent service:

   **socket file**

   ```bash
   sudo nano /usr/lib/systemd/system/io.podman.dhcp.socket

   [Unit]
   Description=DHCP Client for CNI

   [Socket]
   ListenStream=%t/cni/dhcp.sock
   SocketMode=0600

   [Install]
   WantedBy=sockets.target
   ```

   **service file**

   ```bash
   sudo nano /usr/lib/systemd/system/io.podman.dhcp.service
   [Unit]
   Description=DHCP Client CNI Service
   Requires=io.podman.dhcp.socket
   After=io.podman.dhcp.socket

   [Service]
   Type=simple
   ExecStart=/usr/libexec/cni/dhcp daemon
   TimeoutStopSec=30
   KillMode=process

   [Install]
   WantedBy=multi-user.target
   Also=io.podman.dhcp.socket
   ```
4. enable the service:

   ```bash
   sudo systemctl --now enable io.podman.dhcp.socket
   ```
5. (optional) reboot and test the service is working as intended by calling again

   ```bash
   sudo podman run -it --rm --network newnet alpine ip addr
   ```